# php Linkedin-api Logout

Tags: php, linkedin-api

Can anyone tell me if exist a way to log-out linkedin user with PHP. I tried already all methods from [auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/logout) and from [connect2](https://www.connect2.me/linkedin/linkedin-api) but nothing work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no way, I have tried every methods, such as:

```
IN.API.Raw().url('/logout').method('get');
```

and

```
IN.User.logout();
```